# "In another nod to" meaning in the context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Apple launched an online store in Vietnam this week, ***in another nod to*** the growing importance of emerging markets for the iPhone maker.
>
> [The source](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/05/19/tech/apple-southeast-asia-india-opportunity-intl-hnk/index.html)

I think the "another nod to" means "refers to" as indicated in Cambridge dictionary. However, I'm wondering if we can remove 'in' here. How should we understand the phrase in the context (with/without 'in')?

Comment: *in another nod to... = in [further] **recognition** of...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I somehow feel 'in' is unnecessary in the original sentence. How about removing it? Will it still be grammatical?

Comment: You have to have *some* text to represent the connection between Apple's online store launch and "the growing importance of emerging markets". It's syntactically possible to omit ***in*** with both the original and my alternative, but that would be a very poor stylistic choice unless you also replaced the preceding comma by a dash (or removed the comma completely and put brackets round all the following text). Or if you don't like ***in***, you could replace it by ***which is/was***. But note that this is because you're not a native Anglophone - most native speakers would be fine with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 'nod' in this sense is more than a reference; I prefer [this Macmillan definition](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/a-nod-to-towards-something). It's a noun, not a verb (it doesn't mean *refer*), so we have to say that an action *is* a nod to something (a demonstration that they are aware of the growing market in Vietnam).

Comment: How about removing 'in'? *Apple launched an online store in Vietnam this week, another nod to the growing importance of emerging markets for the iPhone maker.*

Comment: See FumbleFingers' comment.